# Hook woocommerce_checkout_order_processed order items issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am working on a WooCommerce project. I need to add some entry based on ordered item in my custom table. If user ordered 3 items then those 3 entry will be place along with some data in my custom table.

For that I used `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook. But I faced some **issue**, that if user adds 4 items in cart and on checkout page if user removed all items except one and finally ordered just 1 item then also in this hook I am getting all 4 items. I am not getting final ordered item in this hook.

So I changed the hook to `woocommerce_thankyou` . But in some case due to some reason user did not come on thank you page or on some credit card payment this hook **did not work**.

So can anyone tell me the best hook which can run after order place no matter if payment done or not and also I should get only ordered items. My WooCommerce version is 3+

**Code :**

```
function wc_function($order_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item_line_id => $item) {
        // Insert data in my custom table
    }
}
//add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed','wc_function', 10, 3);
//add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_function', 10, 1);
```

Thank you !

Comment: how are you getting those items in you hook callback? `$order->get_items()` ??

Comment: Hello @swadhwa, Please check my updated question.

Comment: Yes I am using $order->get_items() to get items.

Comment: can you do it like this once: `wc_get_order( $order_id )->get_items()`

Comment: Yes I tried this one as well. But same I was getting all items including removed.

Comment: What about https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L391-L403, 
as you can see these come right after `$order->save();`

Comment: You mean to use woocommerce_checkout_order_created ?

Comment: @DavidCoder you can try `woocommerce_checkout_order_created` but I suspect it'll still be the same.

Comment: replace `function wc_function($order_id)` with `function wc_function($order_id, $posted_data, $order)` it shouldn't make any difference but u could give it a try: `$order->get_items()`

Comment: I just took a test with `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3 );...etc..`  
and this works as it should, not as you describe it so I suppose the error lies elsewhere than just the hook

Comment: @swadhwa, This works function wc_function($order_id, $posted_data, $order) with $order->get_items(). Now I am getting final items only. Thank you!

Comment: @7uc1f3r, Yes with 3 arguments it is working if we get items direct from arguments. If we use wc_get_order( $order_id )->get_items() then it will return all the items even deleted items from cart  page.

Comment: @DavidCoder so I'm posting this as an answer so that others can find it helpful. make sure to accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do_action` on `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` passes exactly three args, third of which is the `$order` itself. So try using that instead:

```
function wc_function($order_id, $posted_data, $order) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item_line_id => $item) {
        // Insert data in my custom table
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I realise that in woocommerce_checkout_order_processed hook, some times it is adding multiple entries in my custom table. It is not working as expected. Do you have any other hook that can be run exact after the order placed ?

Comment: We have woocommerce_thankyou and I tried as well but somehow if user don't come on thank you page then it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'getswift_delivery_thankyou', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'getswift_delivery_thankyou', 10, 1 );

You may use this hook it's working on my side... if you have any problems then discuss me we will solve them